# Custom WCF Binding equivalent to WSHttpBinding with WS-Addressing turned off

Tags: wcf, wshttpbinding, ws-addressing

I am trying to create a WCF service that needs to be consumed by a Java client. Requirements from the Java client is to disable WS-Addressing. I must have to use WSHttpBinding.  First of all I am bit new to this. I did some quick search online but was not able to figure out if that is the correct solution. Can somebody please point me to right direction ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use http://webservices20.cloudapp.net/ for such issues. You did not specify which security you need. One option is

```
<!-- generated via Yaron Naveh's http://webservices20.blogspot.com/ -->

<customBinding>
  <binding name="NewBinding0">
    <transactionFlow />
    <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" />
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
    <httpsTransport />
  </binding>
</customBinding>

<!-- generated via Yaron Naveh's http://webservices20.blogspot.com/ -->
```

Comment: Thanks Navesh. I did try using your tool but got an exception. Sorry for not mentioning what type of security I need. Following is my current binding.

Comment: <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpUsernameEndpointBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="False" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>