# WCF disable WS-Addressing

Tags: wcf, soap, ws-addressing

I am trying to disable a web service WS-Addressing. I followed the steps passed by Serene Trees in [microsoft forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d4cc4543-347c-44a5-bb1f-969c64a2f288/custom-wshttpbinding-to-disable-wsaddressing?forum=wcf).
She says basicaly to create a custom binding and set messageVersion on the textMessageEncoding element to "Soap12".

But my service still generating references to addressing namespaces.

```
xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" 
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" 
xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"
```

Does anyone know why it occurs and whether I can remove these references?

Comment: The following post seems to address your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708104/custom-wcf-binding-equivalent-to-wshttpbinding-with-ws-addressing-turned-off

Comment: I tried exactly as this post @Seymour but still got the same result

Comment: Maybe it's only one more discrepancy created by .net over soa pattern as the other witch @LadislavMrnka helped me in this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532039/can-i-create-a-service-with-wcf-that-generate-supportingtokens-policy